# How to pass an option to a Grunt task using WebStorm?

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

I have a *Gruntfile.js* in my project, which is parsed by WebStorm (JetBrains IDE for Javascript). The parsed tasks appear in the Grunt view.

Considering the following task (see http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#options) :

```
grunt.registerTask('upload', 'Upload code to specified target.', function(n) {
  var target = grunt.option('target');
  // do something useful with target here
});
```

How can I run `grunt upload --target=staging` using WebStorm ? I can't find a way to pass the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to specify custom CMD options (retrieved via grunt.option()) passed to Grunt task, use Tasks field of Grunt Run configuration, like: '`print -–echo=Hello`' (or '`upload --target=staging`' in your case)

Comment: I tried adding custom options in the field "Tasks" in the window displayed when I right-clic on a task in the Grunt view, then "Edit 'task' settings...". The thing is everytime I try to specify something here, WebStorm seams to reload the gruntfile.js and overrides this field.

Comment: this is by design -  a run configuration with "Tasks" value that differs from a clicked task name can't be reused to run/edit the clicked task. So, WebStorm creates a new configuration when you choose "Edit 'task' settings..." from right-click menu. But your modified configuration is also preserved - you will see it when opening Run/Edit configurations. Find your modified configuration there, select it in run dropdown and use for running your tasks instead of running from right-click menu

Comment: I found the tasks list you're talking about clicking on "Run > Run..." in the main toolbar (shortcut Alt+Maj+F10). Then I realised that the dropdown list of run configurations was displayed on top-right of the window, next to the "Run" symbol. I can launch my custom task including command line options from there. Thank you very much ! :)